# render cache true with expiration date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The rails documentation says that is possible to use `cached: true` on a partial render to cache it, but i'm not able to find out if `expires_in` will work there. Like this:

```
= render template: 'admin/stats/daily_finance', cached: true, expires_in: 1.hour
```

Is this valid?

Answer (score -1):

I believe the answer is 'no' (or not yet).  I've filed an issue for this, along with a monkey patch to make it work: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/33424

Here's the monkey patch, FWIW:

```
module CoreExtensions
module ActionView
  module PartialRenderer
    # Add the ability to specify cache options (expires_by) when using cached collection partials
    def fetch_or_cache_partial(cached_partials, order_by:)
      cache_options = @options.slice(:expires_in) # REVIEW: is Ruby 2.5-requiring code allowed here?
      order_by.map do |cache_key|
        cached_partials.fetch(cache_key) do
          yield.tap do |rendered_partial|
            collection_cache.write(cache_key, rendered_partial, cache_options)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```